# How can I ALTER COLUMN to NOT NULL when the column is indexed

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, indexing, primary-key

I am working in SQL Server 2008 R2 and I have written a stored procedure that adds constraints to several columns in several tables in my database.  However, I am finding that the stored procedure fails because it cannot set a particular column as a Primary Key due to an index on the column.  This is the case for many of the columns in various tables.

Is there a way to ALTER COLUMN to NOT NULL and set it as the PRIMARY KEY without removing the index?  Otherwise, is there a good way to disable or drop the index then enable or recreate it after the ALTER COLUMN statements?

Comment: You've got to drop and recreate the index.  You can script both actions by right-clicking the index in SSMS, and then "Script Index as"

Comment: @Andomar - Thanks for your response.  Is it possible to do this dynamically in the stored procedure?  As I mentioned, this occurs with many columns in many tables.  Is there anyway to programatically check for an index on the field before altering it, drop the index, and recreate it afterword?

Comment: This blog post should get you started: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/07/23/sql-server-puzzle-write-script-to-generate-primary-key-and-foreign-key/

Comment: Yes, you can do this dynamically.  You can use `sys.indexes`, `sys.columns`, `sys.index_columns` and the other system views to determine which indexes are attached to the columns that you want to modify, and determine how they are constructed.  You can then programmatically drop them, make your column modifications, and then recreate the indexes.  None of this is trivial; the code will end up being quite complex, but we use a similar system where I work to automate schema changes and it works quite well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you all for your comments.  After some research, I was able to determine how to do this dynamically using the exact tables mentioned by @mwigdahl.  See the code below:

```
DECLARE @indexName nvarchar(254),
    @tableName nvarchar(254),
    @indexType nvarchar(254),
    @columnName nvarchar(254),
    @isPadded integer,
    @ignore_dup_key integer,
    @allow_row_locks integer,
    @allow_page_locks integer,
    @fillFactor integer

SELECT
    @indexName = i.name, 
    @tableName = o.name,
    @indexType = i.type_desc,
    @columnName = co.[name],
    @isPadded = i.is_padded,
    @ignore_dup_key = i.[ignore_dup_key],
    @allow_row_locks = i.[allow_row_locks],
    @allow_page_locks = i.[allow_page_locks],
    @fillFactor = i.fill_factor
FROM sys.indexes AS i
    INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o ON i.object_id = o.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.index_columns ic on ic.object_id = i.object_id AND ic.index_id = i.index_id
    INNER JOIN sys.columns co on co.object_id = i.object_id AND co.column_id = ic.column_id
WHERE
    i.[type] = 2 AND
    o.[type] = 'U'

DECLARE @sql varchar(max)

SET @sql = 'DROP INDEX [' + @indexName + '] ON [' + @tableName + ']'

EXEC (@sql)

PRINT 'Dropped Index'

-- Do work here

DECLARE @pad_index nvarchar(3),
    @ignore_dup nvarchar(3),
    @row_locks nvarchar(3),
    @page_locks nvarchar(3)

IF @isPadded = 0 SET @pad_index = 'OFF'
ELSE SET @pad_index = 'ON'

IF @ignore_dup_key = 0 SET @ignore_dup = 'OFF'
ELSE SET @ignore_dup = 'ON'

IF @allow_row_locks = 0 SET @row_locks = 'OFF'
ELSE SET @row_locks = 'ON'

IF @allow_page_locks = 0 SET @page_locks = 'OFF'
ELSE SET @page_locks = 'ON'

SET @sql = 'CREATE ' + @indexType + ' INDEX [' + @indexName + '] ON [' + @tableName + ']' + 
    '(' + 
    '[' + @columnName + '] ASC' + 
    ') WITH (' + 
    'PAD_INDEX = ' + @pad_index + ',' + 
    'STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,' + 
    'SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF,' + 
    'IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ' + @ignore_dup + ',' + 
    'DROP_EXISTING = OFF,' + 
    'ONLINE = OFF,' + 
    'ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ' + @row_locks + ',' + 
    'ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ' + @page_locks + ',' + 
    'FILLFACTOR = ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(100),@fillFactor) + ')' + 
    'ON [PRIMARY]'

PRINT @sql

EXEC (@sql)

PRINT 'Created Index'
```

I used the `Script Index As` function in SSMS to see how the index would be created in T-SQL.

Then I queried the `sys.indexes` and `sys.index_columns` tables to determine which properties were available.

The code shows a query against those tables saving those properties to variables and then dropping and recreating the index.  There were a few options that were not available in those tables that I had to hard code.  Does anyone know if those OPTIONS are available somewhere in a system table?

I hope this helps someone else in the future.